# How can I calculate the rate of entries in a time series in PostgreSQL with a moving time window

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas

So I have data like this:

```
index                      price
2015-01-08 07:01:18.601318  10
2015-01-08 07:01:19.100645  10
2015-01-08 07:01:19.600494  24
2015-01-08 07:01:20.101432  22
2015-01-08 07:01:20.102579  235
2015-01-08 07:01:20.600370  1050
2015-01-08 07:01:20.603521  100
2015-01-08 07:01:20.800408  50
2015-01-08 07:01:21.100629  10
2015-01-08 07:01:21.601491  12
2015-01-08 07:01:21.601663  97
```

What I want is to have a moving window of a specified time length behind each entry, say 1 second, and calculate how many entries are within that window.

The result should look something like:

```
index                      price    rate
2015-01-08 07:01:18.601318  10       1
2015-01-08 07:01:19.100645  10       2
2015-01-08 07:01:19.600494  24       3
2015-01-08 07:01:20.101432  22       2
2015-01-08 07:01:20.102579  235      3
2015-01-08 07:01:20.600370  1050     4
2015-01-08 07:01:20.603521  100      4
2015-01-08 07:01:20.800408  50       5
2015-01-08 07:01:21.100629  10       6
2015-01-08 07:01:21.601491  12       4
2015-01-08 07:01:21.601663  97       5
```

This is to calculate the rate at which these entries were entered into the database.

It looks like I need some kind of sliding expanding window but I can't get it to work.

If this is doable with a pandas DataFrame that would also work.
I know I can group them by seconds using a TimeGrouper in pandas and calculate the count of each group but I'm having other issues there with index duplication and also this removes information:

```
df['rate'] = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1s'))['price'].transform('count')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have sliding windows/frames of different row sizes.

This would work for the example (but is pretty hideous):

```
SELECT t1.index, count(*) AS rate
FROM the_table t1
JOIN the_table t2 ON (t2.index BETWEEN t1.index - interval '1s' AND t1.index)
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1;
```

Partitioning by second (rather than the *preceding* second) would be quite easy, of course.

Comment: When trying that I get way to high values. I think the reason is because it creates a cross join. When doing an explain analyze I fetch 22 rows from each table and end up removing 208 leaving me with many duplicates.

Comment: Alright got it to work using distinct and subqueries, unfortunately I'm dealing with quite large datasets making these joins very time consuming.

Comment: Oh yeah, I meant it when I said it was hideous. Out of curiosity, why do you need the window per entry, rather than grouping them by second (ie two entries in the same second will have the same rate)?

Comment: I am interested in what happened the second before each particular entry to be able to analyze e.g. latency on that entry. Say there's a burst of 100 entries one second, all entries grouped into that second will have a rate of 100 while the first entry won't actually be affected with eventual queuing in the system.